# R-sort time by Month,day,Year and then time which is in AM/PM and also convert the time to 24hr format

Tags: r

here is a table in R I have

```
stopdate                             
8/14/2015  11:38:15AM    
8/14/2015  11:47:59AM    
8/14/2015  12:04:36PM    
8/14/2015   3:08:04PM    
8/14/2015   3:30:25PM    
8/14/2015  10:30:26PM    
8/1/2015   11:19:31AM    
8/15/2015   1:49:14PM
```

I would like to sort it by month/day/year and then by time, however its all under one column.

so how can I convert the time to 24 hr format, and then sort it by month/day/year and then by time?

Thank you

Comment: I would suggest you convert the whole thing to a datetime first. See `?as.POSIXct`, and then `?strptime` for all of the possibilities for formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install package `lubridate`. Then, assuming your data frame is named `df1`, you can convert the dates and times and put them in a new column like this:

```
library(lubridate)
df1$datetime <- mdy_hms(df1$stopdate)
```

You can sort (earliest to latest) using:

```
df1 <- df1[order(df1$datetime), ]
```

Comment: Or just `as.POSIXct(df1$stopdate, format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S%p")` and don't install anything.

Comment: `lubridate` is handy for those of us who haven't memorised every strftime format :)